# Does Healing Burst heal enemy crew?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

It says it 'heals all friendly crew in the room' and 'can target your own ship'.

Now I would *assume* that the specification of *friendly* would mean I could board an enemy ship, and use this weapon to heal my assault team **during battle** *without* healing the enemy crewmembers. I have no ships with a transporter to test this. Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Why the downvote? I clearly stated that I wasn't sure of the meaning, it's not like I didn't read it or something. *like last time* SMH

Comment: This question "does not show any research effort" - you don't need a teleporter to test it. It is also is "not useful" because it's just "is this item's description correct?" with no reason given that you'd doubt it; you might as well ask if some random weapon recharge time is correct.

Comment: I disagree. Language is subject to misinterpretation. Numbers are not. Notice, how math is exactly the same in every language.

Comment: But 1) math isn't the same in every language, 2) all the weapon recharge tooltips _are_ slightly wrong, 3) none of that makes this a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, you *can* target your own ship, but don't *have* to do so. It should work wherever your crew happen to be, and is especially useful if you're boarding. It will not heal enemies.